# What is the correct way to document a Python enum in doxygen?

Tags: python, enums, doxygen

I am documenting my Python code using comments instead of Python's own docstrings. It has worked well except for enums. I get this warning for each one of them:

```
warning: Documentation for undefined enum `MyEnum' found.
```

The documentation gets generated, no problem. I want to get rid of the warning.

I have documented it like this:

```
##   @enum    MyEnum
#    This is my enum.  
class MyEnum(Enum):
```

I have ensured that the file contains an @file tag.

All enums are global. I have even tried

```
##   @enum    MyFileName::MyEnum
```

and

```
##   @enum    MyFileName::MyEnum
```

and even the whole chain as it appears in the output.

```
##   @enum    MyFolder::MyFileName::MyEnum
```

but the warning persists.

Comment: You try to document a class as being an enum. the \enum command is to document enums not for documenting classes. I your case te comment would probably be better if you used: ##This is is my class form enums.

Comment: Hmm. You're right. i expected that Doxygen would treat a Python enum differently if I tag it as enum, but it doesnt make a difference. Dont know if thats deliberate or accident. I would have preferred them to be different but Python doesn't think so, neither does Doxygen. Thanks.